# Modify the dates in a huge file (around 1000 rows) using script

Tags: unix, scripting

I have a requirement in which I need to subtract *x* number of days from dates present in a delimited file if the date exists excluding the first and last row. If the date does not exist in the specified field, ignore the same.

For example, `aaa.txt` contains

```
header
abc|20160431|dhadjs|20160325|hjkkj|kllls
ddd||dhajded|20160320|dwdas|hfehf
footer
```

I want the modified file to have the dates subtracted by 10 days. Something like below:-

```
header
abc|20160421|dhadjs|20160315|hjkkj|kllls
ddd||dhajded|20160310|dwdas|hfehf
footer
```

I don't want to use a programming language like Java to read the file but rather use a scripting language on unix. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: is it ok for you to use python || perl?

Comment: I can probably look at perl

Comment: if no one wants to write it in perl, I can prepare a quick solution in python

Comment: You can start with `while IFS="|" read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6; do ... done` and call a function for the different fields in every loop. The function with the date manipulation should be perl or python.